# Routing Circular reference

Tags: php, symfony

Here my `app/config/routing.yml`

```
AppBundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

RapportBundle:
    resource: "@RapportBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /rapport

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

RapportBundle/Controller/RapportController.php

```
<?php

namespace RapportBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class RapportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template
     * @Route("/", name="rapport_index")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        return [];
    }
}
```

And same file for AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

When I launch my index from DefaultController, I got this :

```
Circular reference detected in "/var/www/my-site/app/config/routing_dev.yml" ("/var/www/my-site/app/config/routing_dev.yml" > "/var/www/my-site/app/config/routing.yml" > "/var/www/my-site/app/config/routing_dev.yml").
```

(My routing_dev.yml has not been changed, it's Symfony2 base)

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself :

I Just forgot to add RapportBundle to AppKernel....

Comment: Same trouble while integrating some CMF bundles. The error is quite misleading indeed.